# How to convert login data in json format in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I am new to iOS development. I have created a view which accepts the users phone number and password.

The api that lets a user logs in takes the login data in json format :-

```
{
"login_details":[
        {
            "mobile":"**************",
            "password":"XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to get the textfield data and print it

```
let mobile = phoneTextField.text;
let password = passwordTextField.text;
```

How do I now convert this to required json format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your input data in a `Dictionary` and pass it with the name label like that

```
    let userData = ["mobile":"432423432424","password":"123"]

    let dict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict.setValue(userData, forKey: "login_details")

    let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros)
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

     print(jsonString)
```

Comment: this works fine with predefined values for mobile and password. When I try let userData = ["mobile": "\(mobile)","password": "\(password)"], the backslash gets include in json...any work around...

Comment: should be like that  let userData = `["mobile": "\(mobile)","password": "\(password)"]`

Comment: yes, thats the way it is..don't know why the backslash got removed here

Comment: why don't you do it just with `["mobile": mobile,"password": password]` like that without `" "`

Comment: using that gives error on this line dict.setValue(userData, forKey: "login_details") - cannot convert value of type [string string!].....

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might be help you

```
    var dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict["password"] = "**************"
    dict["mobile"] = "XXXXXXXXX"
    var arr: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.array()
    arr.append(dict)
    var loginDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    loginDict["login_details"] = arr
```

output:

```
Printing description of loginDict:
{
"login_details" =     (
            {
        mobile = XXXXXXXXX;
        password = "**************";
    }
);
}
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
let dict = ["login_details": [["mobile" : mobile, "password": password]]]
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
```

**Swift 2**

```
let dict = ["login_details": [["mobile" : mobile, "password": password]]]
let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:[])
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```